# What is the difference between "bind" and "link"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, nouns

*Bind* and *link* are both verb and noun but the difference in meaning between these words are quite hard for me to catch.

I'd say the "the moral bind of the law" to express that both of them are tied tightly together. On the other hand, *link* would express more an relationship if I see it correctly.

But, when I say that "the system A (computer) is linked/bound with another system B", which of the two, *link* or *bind*, expresses that data flow from one system to another?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Did you look the two words up in a good dictionary? What did you find, and why was it not helpful? On this and other SE sites, [not including the research you've done](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a reason to place the question on hold (you can always edit it in.) Also, though they have the same requirements, have you seen [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)? It's a great site for basic questions about the English language.

Comment: "The moral bind of the law" is borderline nonsense.

Comment: I think "bind" is not used as a noun as often as "bond." As Hot Licks said, "the moral bind of the law" is confusing and doesn't make much sense. if you want to express that morality and law are tied tightly together, you should use a phrase like "the close bond between morality and law." Here's a similar Google Books example: https://books.google.com/books?id=JJooAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=close+bond+between+morality&source=bl&ots=-aIV2dB56L&sig=ltftThftGjCJekyis7SAI1vE4OM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtvNK9rtrLAhWBtoMKHS_vDckQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=close%20bond%20between%20morality&f=false

Comment: @medica: Yes I have and my question is more about the usage than the definition this is why I don't really understand why you put me on hold, although it may suit more the other forum you have mentioned.

Comment: @HotLicks: This one comes from a dictionary. I will get another better one next time ;)

Comment: One needs to understand, too, that "link" and "bind" are terms of computer *jargon*, with specific meanings, often only vaguely related to the dictionary definitions, and often varying from one computer system to the next.  If you want to know what they mean with regard to a specific computer system you need to look them up in the documentation for that computer system.

Comment: @HotLicks: But I'm writting this system and writting this documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then interpret "bind" to mean "connect tightly" and "link" to mean "connect loosely", as you choose terminology.  Once the terminology has been chosen add the specific entries to your documentation to describe each specific meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both link and bind can be used to express two systems in which data flows from one to the other.  The difference is the degree of the relationship.

If two systems share a certain amount of information but are essentially independent then I would choose 'linked'.

> Facebook and LinkedIn are linked because LinkedIn offers users the opportunity to publish updates to Facebook from LinkedIn.

If two systems require that data between the two be synchronized or are tightly related such that one cannot operate effectively without the other I would choose 'bound'.

> The Facebook Messenger App is bound to Facebook because Messenger uses Facebook's credentials and Friend list to function.  users cannot use Messenger without being on Facebook.

Comment: Thank you! It was the answer I was looking for. Sadly I ve less than 15 points and cannot upvote your answer for the time you've spent. Tanks again!